# Finding a geodesic that contains a given point $P$ and intersects any given geodesic orthogonally.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry, geodesic

**Let $P \in H^2,$ and $L$ be a complete geodesic in $H^2.$**

**Prove that there is a unique complete geodesic $L'$ through $P$ and orthogonal to $L$ at some point $Q \in L.$ Moreover, the line segment from $P$ to $Q$ minimizes the distance from $P$ to any point on $L.$**

---

I am not confident in my proof:

I do not understand isometries well and and may have used them incorrectly.

Am I on the right track?

**Solution:**

(1) Consider the case where $L$ is a vertical half-line $$L = \{(x_0,y) \in R^2; y > 0\}.$$ Easily, one can construct a complete geodesic of the hyperbolic plane by centering a half circle at $x_0$ and having it contain the point $P.$ The geodesic $L'$ intersects $L$ orthogonally.

Now, I consider any complete geodesic $L$ in the hyperbolic plane. I state that I can transform this geodesic into the vertical half-line via some compositions of isometries $\phi.$ Since there exists a geodesic $L'$ that contains $P$ and intersects $\phi(L)$ orthogonally at some point $Q',$ and since isometries preserve distances and angles, and since the inverses of isometries are isometries, it follows that $\phi^{-1}(L')$ intersects $L$ orthogonally at point $Q = \phi^{-1}(Q')$ while still containing the point $P.$

I use a similar argument to attempt the second question.

(2) By using some composition of isometries $\phi,$ I can convert $L'$ into the vertical half line. I know that the distance between $\phi(P)$ and $\phi(Q)$ is smaller than the distance between $\phi(P)$ and any other point on the geodesic $\phi(L').$ So, the same is also true for $P$ and $Q.$

Comment: Your question as stated is confusing. Upper case and lower case are mixed up. Also I cannot tell what points are given: Are $P$ and $Q$ both given? If so, can you restate the question to make this clear, and to make clear what are the required hypotheses and conclusions regarding $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Ya. Sure! I copied and pasted the question as it was given to me. Please excuse me! I’ll fix it now

Comment: I find that copying a question from my source into my brain, and then copying it from my brain to whatever I am writing, is a more effective way of reaching quick understanding.

Comment: Hey, Lee. Actually, what may have confused you is that there was a typo! The first letter should have been P, not Q! I just fixed it. Please let me know if it is still confusing!